# How can "select case when" use with group by in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

The goal is "Write a SQL query that calculates total written_premium_dollar_amount for 2016 and total written_premium_dollar_amount for 2017."

The table sample is:

```
id  state  exposure_month  written_premium_dollar_amount
1    OH     201606                 104  
1    OH     201606                 50   
2    OH     201703                 13.34
`
`
`
```

I wrote a query :

```
select exposure_month,sum(written_premium_dollar_amount) as totalWrittenPremium
from finacials 
where exposure_month like '2016%' 
or exposure_month like '2017%' 
group by exposure_month
```

the result is

```
exposure_month  totalWrittenPremium
201606              154
201608              99
201609              93
201610              0.2
201612              211.55
201701              37.88
201702              114
201703              163 
`
`
`
```

And now, I would like to group the total Written Premium by year. The code I wrote is:

```
select *, 
case when left(exposure_month,4)='2016' then '2016'
when left(exposure_month,4)='2017' then '2017'
else 'others'
end exposure_year, sum(written_premium_dollar_amount) as totalWrittenPremium
from finacials
group by exposure_year
```

I got an error Invalid column name 'exposure_year'.
I understand exposure_year can't be a condition of group by because exposure_year colunm is not exist in the original table. Also, I can't say group by *. Therefore, my questions would be:

1. Is there any way to achieve my goal?
2. Can exposure_year be added to the original table and use group by exposure_year? If it works, how  can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try to use the query like below.

```
select exposure_month,sum(written_premium_dollar_amount) as totalWrittenPremium
from finacials 
where exposure_month like '2016%' 
or exposure_month like '2017%' 
group by  left(exposure_month,4)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. There is an error but I fixed it. Using 
select left(exposure_month,4),sum(written_premium_dollar_amount)

Answer (score 0):

Query.

```
select case when left(exposure_month,4)='2016' then '2016'
            when left(exposure_month,4)='2017' then '2017'
            else 'others'
       end exposure_year, sum(written_premium_dollar_amount) as totalWrittenPremium
from finacials
group by case when left(exposure_month,4)='2016' then '2016'
              when left(exposure_month,4)='2017' then '2017'
              else 'others'
         end
```